# Routers Upstairs / Downstairs, allow them to talk?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, tcpip

I recently installed another router upstairs because the downstairs one didn't reach via WIFI. The second router takes its WAN connection from downstairs (I only have 1 physical connection to the internet via an ADSL router ( downstairs) ).

So everything is working great, I have strong internet in all cases but downstairs is on 192.168.1.x and upstairs is on 192.168.0.x

So hence pc's upstairs can't see downstairs and the opposite is also true.

Whats the best way round this?

My downstairs router is ip 192.168.1.1, so do I force it to server DHCP from .10 to .50 for example and then upstairs router configure it to be 192.168.1.2 (same network now ?? ) and get it to servre DHCP 51 to 100 for example. SO no conflicts.

Any advice or better way to do it ? Not sure if this would work or is the recommended way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you bridging your routers?

Comment: I have a cable from my downstairs router plugged into the WAN connection on my upstairs router

Comment: Will it just switch to Access Point mode & let one machine handle all the DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to give the upstairs router a static ip.  Open up a web browser and punch in the current IP of the upstairs router and change settings from there. Make the subnet mask and default gateway the same as the downstairs one.

And yes you can set the DHCP to be staggered a bit so you don't have any computers trying to take the same IP.